# How I can use two dates parameters for two different between without repeat using spring boots?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new at spring boots, and I'm trying use it for a query, I'll use 2 instant parameters, and use this instant to compare them to two instant of my object (DateBegin and StartedWork).
The code below work, but for that I have to send two times my first date and last date.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginBetweenOrStartedWorkBetween (Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate, Instant firstDateAgain, Instant lastDateAgain);
```

I can't find an example of that situation. I try things like that:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginOrStartedWorkBetween (Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate);
```

But i get the error below at build:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query
>   for method public abstract java.util.Collection 
>   com...MyClass.findByDateBeginOrStartedWorkBetween
>   (java.time.Instant,java.time.Instant)!  No parameter available for
>   part startedWork BETWEEN (2): [IsBetween, Between] NEVER.

Can I use and how I can use just one time each date parameter in spring boots?

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the first one so it works with how Spring Data derives queries, but define the second method as a default method for your convenience:

```
Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginBetweenOrStartedWorkBetween(Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate, Instant firstDateAgain, Instant lastDateAgain);

default Collection<MyClass> findByDateBeginOrStartedWorkBetween(Instant firstDate, Instant lastDate) {
    return findByDateBeginBetweenOrStartedWorkBetween(firstDate, lastDate, firstDate, lastDate);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the awnser. I just wanna wait some time to see if someone have an awnser what don't need a workaround. If no one have other option, i'll sinalize you as correct one.